# where does create-react-app specify which port to run on

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

My question isn't how to change which port create-react-app runs on.

My question is where does create-react-app specify port 3000.

I don't want to change it I just want to understand how it sets it.

I've searched for 3000 but it just comes up in a bunch of comments not the actual setting.

Is it in compiled code some where? Do I need to unpack it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default port is set in the start script of `react-scripts` [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/packages/react-scripts/scripts/start.js#L55):

```
const DEFAULT_PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
```

Comment: great thank you! I was looking in react-scripts but was looking in config so couldn't find it. Appreciated!